# como achar a média em uma tabela de classes

Tags: r

[image: tabela de classes para número de divorcios]

Gostaria de saber como faço para encontrar a média na tabela de frequências usando R. Eu tentei fazendo:

```
sum(n.div * p.m)/5000
```

Mas o resultado é muito discrepante (`6900`). Quando faço em qualquer outra tabela, o mesmo procedimento da certo.  A variável `p.m` é o ponto médio da classe e a var `n.div` é a frequência e `Fac` a frequência acumulada. Segue código:

```
anos.casamen <- c("0|--6","06|--12","12|--18","18|--24","24|--30")

n.div <- c(2800,1400,600,150,050)

cartorio <- data.frame(anos.casamen,n.div)

cartorio["Fac"]<- cumsum(n.div)

cartorio["porcentagem"]<- round(prop.table(n.div),digits = 4)

medio <- sum(cartorio$n.div * cartorio$p.m)/length(n.div)
```

Comment: Não seria `sum(cartorio$n.div * cartorio$p.m)/cartorio$Fac[length(n.div)]`? Ou de maneira mais sucinta: `with(cartorio, sum(n.div*p.m)/sum(n.div))`

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta Isso devia ser uma resposta. Outra pode ser `with(cartorio, weighted.mean(p.m, porcentagem))`.

Comment: sim, realmente da 6.9 mas não entendo como este número me ajuda a entender a média dentro da frequência que é n.div ( número de divórcios) pode ser 6.9 que é um valoe extremamente pequeno ou 6900 que passa da máxima

Comment: Não é um valor pequeno, há 4200 valores entre 0 e 12 mas só 800 entre 12 e 30. Esse valor ajuda a entender que a distribuição dos dados é assimétrica.

Comment: sim, compreendi, muito obrigado, a explicação da assimetria me fez entender, até por não ser uma média linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira de calcular médias ponderadas é com `weighted.mean`.

```
with(cartorio, weighted.mean(p.m, porcentagem))
#[1] 6.9
```

Dá o mesmo resultado que a solução no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/457778/como-achar-a-m%c3%a9dia-em-uma-tabela-de-classes#comment871805_457778) do usuário [Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/117168/carlos-eduardo-lagosta).

Num comentário está dito que o valor da média ponderada é muito pequeno. Na verdade não é pequeno tendo em conta que a distribuição dos dados é assimétrica:

1. há 4200 valores entre 0 e 12
2. mas só 800 entre 12 e 30.

Esse valor da média ajuda a entender que a distribuição dos dados é assimétrica. Isso também pode ser visto graficamente.

```
with(cartorio, barplot(setNames(n.div, anos.casamen)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dados completos**

```
anos.casamen <- c("0|--6","06|--12","12|--18","18|--24","24|--30")
n.div <- c(2800,1400,600,150,050)
cartorio <- data.frame(anos.casamen,n.div)

cartorio$Fac <- cumsum(cartorio$n.div)
cartorio$porcentagem <- c(0.56, 0.28, 0.12, 0.03, 0.01)
cartorio$p.m <- c(3, 9, 15, 21, 27)

cartorio 
#  anos.casamen n.div  Fac porcentagem p.m
#1        0|--6  2800 2800        0.56   3
#2      06|--12  1400 4200        0.28   9
#3      12|--18   600 4800        0.12  15
#4      18|--24   150 4950        0.03  21
#5      24|--30    50 5000        0.01  27
```

Comment: sim, só não entendo o resultado porque dá 6.9,  quando faço em outras tabelas sai um resultado entre os números da coluna de frequência, e 6.9 é muito pequeno e 6900 passa do valoe máximo

Comment: @Di82Rquant Não é um número pequeno, veja a edição.